# How to subscribe to .NET control events from an external .NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

My company has a lot of products written in C# .NET Windows Forms. Different teams around the world manage different products so I don't have the liberty to do major changes in host applications but minor ones can be done.

I want to write a generic library which, given a control handle, can subscribe to all events of that control. Since both host application and library are in C# .NET, I hope there is a pretty easy way to do it.

Comment: Depends on what you achieving. Is is about sharing data between applications?

Comment: This is not likely to work, as `Control.FromHandle` can only return controls from the current `AppDomain`. Your best bet AFAIK is capturing these controls as `NativeWindow` objects and intercepting their `WndProc`.

Comment: There isn't a pretty way to do it.. same as @Rotem said: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx   You can use the WndProc and hooks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121556/how-do-i-hook-into-other-programs-in-windows

Comment: @wes if you have a `Handle` to some control, you can use `NativeWindow` to intercept the messages and `fire` the corresponding events. Why do you think it's not a pretty way to do it? Of course it's not a `native` way, it's a `.NET` way. With `native` way, you have to use `GetWindowLong` and `SetWindowLong` to  change the default `WindowProc` of a control/window.

Comment: By "pretty," I mean it's not as simple as using a DLL or class and overriding methods. NativeWindow is definitely much easier to use (as far as initial setup) than the native methods. Generally, especially within the same organization, it seems as though there should be a better approach rather than the above solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment discussion, to meet the requirements of your question, your best bet would probably be the `NativeWindow` solution.

However, I would still recommend that you speak with your colleagues to see if there's another alternative that might make things easier on your part. **If you create solutions for your customers based on solutions provided by your colleagues, there is a strong potential that you will have to rewrite your customized solutions as often as your colleagues deploy their latest updates...**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace NativeWindowApplication
{

    // Summary description for Form1.
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        private MyNativeWindowListener nwl;
        private MyNativeWindow nw;

        internal void ApplicationActivated(bool ApplicationActivated)
        {
            // The application has been activated or deactivated
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Application Active = " + ApplicationActivated.ToString());
        }

        private Form1()
        {
            this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
            this.Text = "Form1";

            nwl = new MyNativeWindowListener(this);
            nw = new MyNativeWindow(this);

        }

        // The main entry point for the application.
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }

    // NativeWindow class to listen to operating system messages.
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    internal class MyNativeWindowListener : NativeWindow
    {

        // Constant value was found in the "windows.h" header file.
        private const int WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;

        private Form1 parent;

        public MyNativeWindowListener(Form1 parent)
        {

            parent.HandleCreated += new EventHandler(this.OnHandleCreated);
            parent.HandleDestroyed += new EventHandler(this.OnHandleDestroyed);
            this.parent = parent;
        }

        // Listen for the control's window creation and then hook into it. 
        internal void OnHandleCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Window is now created, assign handle to NativeWindow.
            AssignHandle(((Form1)sender).Handle);
        }
        internal void OnHandleDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Window was destroyed, release hook.
            ReleaseHandle();
        }
        [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            // Listen for operating system messages 

            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:

                    // Notify the form that this message was received. 
                    // Application is activated or deactivated,  
                    // based upon the WParam parameter.
                    parent.ApplicationActivated(((int)m.WParam != 0));

                    break;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

    // MyNativeWindow class to create a window given a class name.
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    internal class MyNativeWindow : NativeWindow
    {

        // Constant values were found in the "windows.h" header file.
        private const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000,
                          WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000,
                          WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C;

        private int windowHandle;

        public MyNativeWindow(Form parent)
        {

            CreateParams cp = new CreateParams();

            // Fill in the CreateParams details.
            cp.Caption = "Click here";
            cp.ClassName = "Button";

            // Set the position on the form
            cp.X = 100;
            cp.Y = 100;
            cp.Height = 100;
            cp.Width = 100;

            // Specify the form as the parent.
            cp.Parent = parent.Handle;

            // Create as a child of the specified parent
            cp.Style = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE;

            // Create the actual window 
            this.CreateHandle(cp);
        }

        // Listen to when the handle changes to keep the variable in sync
        [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        protected override void OnHandleChange()
        {
            windowHandle = (int)this.Handle;
        }

        [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            // Listen for messages that are sent to the button window. Some messages are sent 
            // to the parent window instead of the button's window. 

            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case WM_ACTIVATEAPP:
                    // Do something here in response to messages 
                    break;
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
}
```